# restarting iteration and prompting for user input until given hash values are met

Tags: ruby

This is the beginning of a tic tac toe program. I want the program to loop through, and then reset back for more input until a given scenario of hash values is met. As of right now it asks for input and displays it on my grid one time. If I try to wrap it in a loop the program prints the first input until it crashes.

```
@entries = {1=>" ", 2=>" ", 3=>" ", 4=>" ", 5=>" ", 6=>" ", 7=>" ", 8=>" ",9=>" "}

def choice(n)
  puts "pick a space!"
  name = gets.chomp
  name2 = name.to_i
  n.each do |key,value|
    if name2 == key 
      @entries[key]= "X"
      puts "\t\t #{@entries[1]} | #{@entries[2]} | #{@entries[3]} "
      puts "\t\t-----------"
      puts "\t\t #{@entries[4]} | #{@entries[5]} | #{@entries[6]} "
      puts "\t\t-----------"
      puts "\t\t #{@entries[7]} | #{@entries[8]} | #{@entries[9]} "
    end
  end
end

choice(@entries)
```

Comment: Your question is muddy. Look at your first sentence. Suppose you began a conversation that way. How could you expect anyone to understand that or even know which way the conversation was going. You are effectively saying, "Here's my code. Please debug it.". You need to first explain what you are trying to do, without any reference to your code. When applicable, augment that with a simple example that includes the desired return value.

Comment: What is the `n.each` loop supposed to achieve (you don't have to traverse an entire hash in order to set a single value)? If this is tic tac toe, then why do you assign the slot's number to the slot (`@entries[key]= name2`) instead of `"X"` or `"O"`? Why do you refer directly to `@entries` within the `choice` method, although it was passes as an argument `n`?

Comment: I edited it to equal "X" instead of name2.  The point of the loop was to iterate through the hash and if the users answer matched a key than a "X" is placed in the corresponding square of the grid. You asked why I traversed through the entire hash....I did so because that's the only way I know of right now to check if that value exists.

Comment: So any idea how I can keep giving input instead of the program ending after the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choice` function currently expects a parameter, that is never used. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, but certainly, the function should use the parameter received, or it should not receive a parameter at all.

If the goal is to fill all the sockets, one might iterate unless they are filled:

```
loop do
  break "Completed!" if @entries.all? { |k, v| k == v }

  choice()
end
```

Comment: Isn't n the parameter that I used for n.each?

Comment: Oh, indeed. Never call parameters a single letter. My bad.

Comment: Noted. if I put the code in a loop like you suggested it will keep printing my grid until the program crashes instead of what I want which is to put an X in one square then get prompted again for the next until there is 3 in a row.